# Clear table data in SQL

Tags: oracle, replace

I hope there is no post limit since I have posted more than once today. :-P 
Now I have a table in OracleSQL. I noticed there are some useless signs  and want to delete them. The way I do it is to replace all of them. Below is my table and my query. 
[image]

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN WORD IN ('!', '"', '@','""') Then ''
  ELSE WORD END 
FROM TERM_FREQUENCY;
```

It is not giving me an error, but these special characters are not going away either... Any thoughts?

Comment: First thing that jumps out is that you have a table `term_frequency` and you use `term-frequency` in your query.

Comment: You'll get better (and faster) responses if you tag your questions more carefully... And I just noticed you significantly changed the question after VMai answered it and addressed the ORA error you were getting, with should therefore be the accepted answer, even if it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

A little typo of yours: you use - instead of _

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN WORD IN ('!', '"', '@','""') Then ''
  ELSE WORD END 
-- FROM TERM-FREQUENCY;   --This is where the problem is.
FROM TERM_FREQUENCY;      -- Because your table is named TERM _ FREQUENCY
```

Answer (score 0):

You originally tagged your question with 'replace' but then didn't use that function in your code. You're comparing each whole `word` to those fixed strings, not seeing if it contains any of them.

You can either use nested `replace` calls to remove one character at a time:

```
select replace(replace(word, '!', null), '"', null) from ...
```

... which would be tedious and rely on you identifying every character you didn't want; or you could use a regular expression only keep alphabetic characters, which I suspect is what you're really after:

```
select regexp_replace(word, '[^[:alpha:]]', null) from ...
```

[Quick demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/132).

You might also want to use `lower` or `upper` to get everything into the same case, as you probably don't really want to count different capitalisation differently either.